# Appending/Concatenating String Arguments

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, powershell-3.0

I want to execute a command that looks like this:

```
# $IncludeTraits is a String[]
$exe = "C:\Foo.exe";
$traits;
foreach ($IncludeTrait in $IncludeTraits)
{
    if ($IncludeTrait -ne $null -and $IncludeTrait -ne "")
    {
        $traits = $traits + "-trait `"$IncludeTrait`" "
    }
}

& $exe $traits
```

The final command should look like:

```
Foo.exe -trait "One" -trait "Two" -trait "Three"
```

If I manually write the command above it works but not using my string concatenated code. How can I get this working using string concatenation?

Comment: what happens if you Write-Output "$exe $traits" Do you see the command Foo.exe -trait "One" -trait "Two" -trait "Three"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use string concatenation. Collect your arguments in an array:

```
$traits = foreach ($IncludeTrait in $IncludeTraits) {
  if ($IncludeTrait) { '-trait'; $IncludeTrait }
}
```

Then run the command with that array:

```
& $exe $traits
```

or use [splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx):

```
& $exe @traits
```